# Visual Basic Split() returning null

Tags: vb.net, file, split

Code for reading and splitting from file:

```
Public Sub LoadAccount()
    currentfilereader = New StreamReader(filename)
    Dim Seperator As Char = " "c
    For count As Integer = 0 To NumUsers - 1
        textstring = currentfilereader.ReadLine
        Dim words() As String = currentfilereader.ReadLine.Split(Seperator)
        Username = words(0)
        Password = words(1)
        If words(2) = "1" Then
            AccessGranted = True
        Else
            AccessGranted = False
        End If
        Users(count, 0) = Username
        Users(count, 1) = Password
        Users(count, 2) = AccessGranted
    Next
    currentfilereader.Close()
End Sub
```

Code for logging in:

```
Public Sub Login()
    Dim InvalidUsername, InvalidPassword As Boolean
    InvalidUsername = True
    InvalidPassword = True
    LoginName = Form1.tbun.Text
    LoginPassword = Form1.tbpw.Text
    For count As Integer = 0 To NumUsers - 1
        If LoginName = Users(count, 0) Then
            InvalidUsername = False
            If LoginPassword = Users(count, 1) Then
                InvalidPassword = False
                CurrentUsername = LoginName
                CurrentPassword = LoginPassword
                CurrentAccessGranted = Users(count, 2)
                loggedin = True
            Else
                MsgBox("Invalid Password")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Invalid Username")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Code for calculating number of users:

```
Public Sub NumberOfUsers()
    currentfilereader = New StreamReader(filename)
    NumUsers = File.ReadAllLines("Accounts.txt").Length
    MsgBox("There are " & NumUsers & " users")
End Sub
```

I have added a `MsgBox` to show the number of users to make sure all is working fine which returns the value of 2, since I currently have 2 lines in the text file, "a a 1" and "b b 1".

However when this line runs, `Dim words() As String = currentfilereader.ReadLine.Split(Seperator)`, it returns null.

The purpose of subtracting 1 from the `NumUsers` in the count is since the count starts at zero along with the array. Meaning that if I didn't it would check 3 times if there is only 2 users in the file. But I just can't seem to figure out what is wrong and why it is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

You call `ReadLine` twice for each user:

```
textstring = currentfilereader.ReadLine
Dim words() As String = currentfilereader.ReadLine.Split(Seperator)
```

This means that for the first user you read both lines, and for the second user you read nothing, leading to the empty split array.

Replace

`Dim words() As String = currentfilereader.ReadLine.Split(Seperator)`

With

`Dim words() As String = textstring.Split(Seperator)`